# SQLite3::SQLException: near "at": syntax error

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I keep getting this error when trying to loop through the jobs i have , here is the code :

```
- @jobs.each do |job|
  %h2= job.title
  %p= job.company
```

this exception the :"SQLite3::SQLException: near "at": syntax error" its not identifying the "-" at the beginning of the line. My file is a .html.haml file.

This is the job controller :

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_job, only: [:show, :edit , :update , :destroy]

    def index
        @jobs=Job.all.order("created at DESC")
    end 

    def show 
    end

    def new
        @job=Job.new 
    end

    def create 
        @job=Job.new[job_params]
        if(@job.save)
            redirect_to @job
        else 
            render "New"
        end 
    end

    def edit
    end 

    def update
    end

    def destroy
    end

    def job_params
        params.require(:job).permit(:title , :description , :company , :url)
    end

    def find_job
        @job=Job.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

also the application_job

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  # Automatically retry jobs that encountered a deadlock
  # retry_on ActiveRecord::Deadlocked

  # Most jobs are safe to ignore if the underlying records are no longer available
  # discard_on ActiveJob::DeserializationError
end
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is in the view. We should see how you initialize that `@jobs`

Comment: Please post the full error message from the log file including the stack trace.

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: near "at": syntax error):
    1: - @jobs.each do |job|
    2:   %h2= job.title
    3:   %p= job.company
    4:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your order query has a typo: `order("created at DESC")` should be `order("created_at DESC")`